# Specify path to CSS image in web.config

Tags: html, css, asp.net, path

**Problem**

In CSS files are css-rules that sets background-image for some element. As images can be moved in different places (even on different servers) i would like to have some variable that i can use in CSS files as "main" path to image.

Is there any solution for this?

---

Setting paths to images in inline way is only one solution that i can image for now.

Comment: Not with css, but you can create a folder called assets and have all image directories in there even network directories that link on different servers.

Comment: @keikoku92, no, php i can't use :D

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou, can you give me more details about it? how can i store image directories in assets folder and how can i use it in css file? Thanks

Comment: can you use php? if so you can create a variable $image_link="location/pic1.jpg"; and you would use it something like that: <?php echo "<img src=' .$image_link. ' />" ?>

Comment: 1st, you need to explain (As images can be moved in different places, even on different servers). who is moving them, you?? and if so why are you doing that. its not the norm. when it comes to images, espeically 1000's of them the path to images are usually stored in adatabase so when they move around as you say the path gets updated there in the db